# Shrinking gaps in glued-down hardwood floor

Tags: floor, adhesive, hardwood

So our birch floor has a lot of gaps near the kitchen sink. They are uneven in size, and it's as if the pieces have drifted toward sink.
I've just spent some quality time prying crud out of the gaps, and now I'm wondering how
to move the boards tight again.

The boards were glued down probably 10 are 20 years ago (I'm in Quebec). Is there a way to soften the glue underneath so that the boards can float? I'm thinking heat.

Comment: Are you sure they're glued down, not nailed down? Are you sure it's real wood flooring not some sort of manufactured laminate flooring? A picture or two of the issues might also be helpful.

Comment: I'm sure it's solid wood and not nailed. A rare earth magnet easily finds the nails in an older section of flooring, but not this one.

Answer (score 1):

Near the kitchen sink is a likely clue. Odds are the floor (whether glued down or nailed down or even both) got wet and swelled, which has the power to overcome gluing and nailing. Then it's dried, and the boards don't move back, they stay where they are and get narrower.

I don't know of any method other than taking the floor up and reinstalling it (if it survives being taken up) or installing a new one to fix that. If you fill the gaps, the next time the floor gets damp or wet it will move further because instead of expanding into the gaps, it will expand against the filler material and shove the next board over some more, until the boards hit the wall framing and start bulging upwards.

Moving the boards back would require applying tremendous force to the edge of the boards that's presumably hidden under the cabinets. That's impractical.

Comment: The cabinet base is covered by a section of quarter round, and peeking behind it, I see the end of the floor. Might be enough to pry against if I can somehow soften the glue. I figure it already moved one way, so what's stopping it from moving back, except lack of a clever trick?